# How to get the number each record appears in a table

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

Hey there, in my rewrite i need to get the number of times each record of a table appears, and return an array, with some neat php function, preferibly something fast.

Table looks like:

```
remote_ip     || random_table_data    || more_data || and_more_table_data

201.101.124.1     3
201.101.124.1     4
205.105.105.5     3
205.105.105.5     4
```

And i need to get an array like in:

```
Array ( [201.101.124.1] => 2 [205.105.105.5] => 2 )
```

since in this example those ips appear two times each.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you're basically trying to `COUNT` distinct records. You can accomplish that with a simple mix of the `COUNT()` function and the `GROUP BY` clause.

```
$sql = "SELECT remote_ip, COUNT(remote_ip) AS cnt FROM tbl GROUP BY remote_ip;";
$result = mysql_query($sql);

$array = array();
while ($rs = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $array[$rs['remote_ip']] = $rs['cnt'];
}
```